# How to get all element of a bucket in HashMap

Tags: java

As we know HashMap keep all data in buckets(calculate bucket location on basis of hashCode()).

is there any way to get all element of bucket (**without iterating whole bucket**)

like

```
my hashCode()  method generates hashcode like (**bkt1,bkt2,bkt3 and bkt4**)
in **bkt1** we have values like (**val1,val2,val3 and val4**)
in **bkt2** we have values like ( **val5,val6 and val7**)
and so on ....
```

can i get all values of bucket bkt1 **without iterating whole map**

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it merely for debugging purposes, or do you have functional reasons to access individual buckets?

Comment: i have to save some employ in hashMap, and i want to categorize on basis of salary 
like 
2000$ - 3000$
3001$ - 3500$
3501$ - 4000$

now if i want employ those have salary between 2000$ - 3000$  i just pick first bucket element 
i don't want  iterate whole hashMap

Comment: I must admit I don't see why you would want to access hash buckets for that. Are the employees hashed by salary or something? It sounds like a `TreeMap` is what you want instead, if anything.

Comment: i have to save some employ in hashMap, and i want to categorize on basis of salary like 2000$ - 3000$ 3001$ - 3500$ 3501$ - 4000$ now if i want employ those have salary between 2000$ - 3000$ i just pick first bucket element i don't want iterate whole hashMap

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how hash tables work. You should probably read back up on them a bit.

Answer (score 7):

You cannot get all elements of a bucket of a java HashMap. You cannot even get *any* elements of a bucket of a java HashMap. That's because the concept of a bucket is internal to the implementation of a HashMap, so it is not exposed by HashMap. There are no public methods of HashMap that deal with buckets in any way.

(And thank goodness for that! I don't want to even *think* how unnecessarily complicated the interface of HashMap would be if the concept of buckets was exposed.)

Since buckets are not exposed, you do not have any means of observing them other than with a debugger.

In order to have control over the buckets you would need to implement the hash map yourself. It is not terribly difficult, but it is not a walk in the park either. However, the chances of you coming up with a HashMap implementation that performs anywhere near as well as the built-in java HashMap are astronomically slim.

The only control you have over the buckets in a hash-map is indirect: it depends on how good your hash-function is. So, just make sure that your objects implement a good hash function.

> A good hash function is a hash function which yields a wide distribution of hash values.

This will give you as many different buckets as possible, with as few elements in each bucket as possible, which is what you want for optimal performance.

In the general case, if you just build your hash function using `Objects.hash( ... )` like everyone else, your hash function will be just fine. You can check how wide the distribution is by examining how often it yields the same hash-code for two different keys. In the general case, you will find that very seldom, if ever, does it yield the same hash-code for two different keys, so everything is good.

No need to be worrying about things that are quite good as they are.

Comment: what should be the bucket no and bucket size in HashMap. So, i can design my hashCode() according to that , like i have to save 500 record in map so what should be the no. of bucket  to perform well

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, or if you are asking anything, (I do not see any questionmark,) but hashmaps have the concept of a load factor, which is the only other thing you can control besides writing a hash function with a wide distribution.  A reasonable number for the load factor is 75%, which is also the default load factor, and the chances of achieving better performance if you change it are astronomically slim.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mike Nakis's answer, if your intention is just to get an object from a `Map` via an `index`, use the interface methode `Object get(key)`.